# AJAX repsonse Variable Concatenation error

Tags: php, ajax

I want to try here at stacksoverflow to found a fix to my code problem I'm not that good in coding sorry. Here I want to start by having my code like this

```
$select_query = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myname = "gelli";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$select_query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

$fullname = $row['fullname'];
$output.='<p>My Name</p>
          <input type = "hidden" value = '.$fullname.' id = "fullname">';
}
```

here you can see in my approach by adding the variable inside value it will output `value = "Gelli Espiritu" id = "fullname"` but in my error it output like this `value = "Gelli" Espiritu id = "fullname"` it goes outside the double quote? every data goes with that error other example `value = "John" Does id = "fullname"`; 
thank you (i did not include the ajax request because there's no problem there just the concatenation) :)

Comment: Fix quotes please.

Comment: You want to output HTML. That requires that you actually output valid HTML, that is encoding values properly. Let me search existing resources for you ... .

Comment: thank you for your answers now i know the answer is `htmlspecialchars()`